# $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(x)e^{inx}dx \to 0 \text{ as }n \to \infty$ as an extension of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\{ f_n\}$ be a sequence of Schwartz functions converging to a Schwartz funtion $f$ pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$ and dominated by another Schwartz function $g$:
\begin{equation}
f_n \to f \text{ pointwise and } \lvert f_n \vert \leq g
\end{equation}

Then, does the following limit hold?
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(x)e^{inx}dx \to 0 \text{ as }n \to \infty
\end{equation}

This seems like an extension of the Riemann Lebesgue lemma, but trickier to prove since I cannot use the DCT. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(x)e^{inx}dx -\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{inx}dx| \leq \int |f_n-f| \to 0$ by DCT and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{inx}dx \to 0$ by Riemann Lebesgue. Hence, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(x)e^{inx}dx \to 0$.